# Not understanding lags and window in R

Tags: r

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how lags and windows work. Conceptually it seems simple: lag basically shifts the data backwards or forward by number of 'rows', and window is like a 'select' operation, telling what data to use based on a start and end time (that's as far as I've gotten in my understanding.

Here's some code from 'Hands On Time Series Analysis with R'

```
library(TSstudio)
data(USVSales)
lags  <- function(ts.obj, l) {
ts_merged <- NULL
## Creating n lags
for (i in 1:l) {
    ## So, for each lag in 1:l, this adds the ts.obj, lagged by i
    ## to ts_merged, so by the end of this loop we have
    ## ts(lag=-1), ts(lag=-2) ..., ts(lag=-l)
    ts_merged <- ts.union(ts_merged, stats::lag(ts.obj,k=-i))
}
## Merge with the original series (adds the original)
ts_merged <- ts.union(ts.obj,ts_merged)
## set the column names (but how do we know that the first
## 'column' is the original?)
colnames(ts_merged <- c("y",paste0("y_",1:i)))
## Removing NAs as results of lag creation
ts_merged <- window(ts_merged,
                    start=start(ts.obj)+l, 
                    end=end(ts.obj))
return(ts_merged)
}
```

I made two different versions of that lag function, one based on the book code, (its result will be named 'book') the other identical, but with the call to window() commented out (output named 'windowless')

The book example continues thusly ...

```
> book <- book_lags(USVSales,l=3)
> head(book)
          y    y_1    y_2    y_3
[1,] 1304.6 1483.8 1148.7 1077.5
[2,] 1373.0 1304.6 1483.8 1148.7
[3,] 1183.8 1373.0 1304.6 1483.8
[4,] 1164.4 1183.8 1373.0 1304.6
[5,] 1207.2 1164.4 1183.8 1373.0
[6,] 1029.6 1207.2 1164.4 1183.8
```

My code produces the following

```
> windowless <- windowless_lags(USVSales,l=3)
> head(windowless)
      y    y_1    y_2    y_3
[1,]  885.2     NA     NA     NA
[2,]  994.7  885.2     NA     NA
[3,] 1243.6  994.7  885.2     NA
[4,] 1191.2 1243.6  994.7  885.2
[5,] 1203.2 1191.2 1243.6  994.7
[6,] 1254.7 1203.2 1191.2 1243.6
```

If I then apply the call to window to the "windowless" output, I get the same output as from the book

```
head(window(windowless,start=start(windowless)+3,
 end=end(windowless)))
      y    y_1    y_2    y_3
[1,] 1304.6 1483.8 1148.7 1077.5
[2,] 1373.0 1304.6 1483.8 1148.7
[3,] 1183.8 1373.0 1304.6 1483.8
[4,] 1164.4 1183.8 1373.0 1304.6
[5,] 1207.2 1164.4 1183.8 1373.0
[6,] 1029.6 1207.2 1164.4 1183.8
```

I don't understand why the first row '(head(window(windowless,...'  doesn't equal the 4th row of 'windowless'. Where does 1304.6 come from?

What am I missing?

Comment: The question defines a function `lags` but then does not use it and we don't know what the functions it uses are.  The one thing I can see is that `start(ts.obj) + 1` is incorrect as `start(ts.obj)` is a 2-vector containing a year and month number and adding 1 adds 1 to the both the year and month.  Note that both zoo and collapse package have vectorized lag functions (lag.zoo, flag) which allow you to generate many lags at once.

Comment: Sorry. The function lags is The original definition from the book. I called it in my example “book_lags” to indicate that it was the function from the book. 

And it’s not “+1“, is “+l”, the parameter in the function call. 

I know. It’s bad to ‘l’, but it’s what is used in the book and I copied and paste it out of the code they provide.

Comment: Also, the series is a monthly series and my understanding was that if you add any number to the start of the series it adds that number of months. Please advise if I’m wrong about that. 

But I’m typing from my iPad. I’ll go off and check to see whether that’s true.

Comment: Try `tt <- ts(1:12, start = c(2000, 1), freq = 12); window(tt, start = start(tt) + 0:1)`

Answer (score 1):

The mystery is that the `start' keyword in window() can be given a single number, but (in this case)  it's interpreted as being **both** the year and month increment.

```
> foo <- ts(data=1:60,frequency=12)
> ts_info(foo)
The foo series is a ts object with 1 variable and 60  observations
Frequency: 12 
Start time: 1 1 
End time: 5 12 

> bar <- window(foo,start=start(foo)+3,end=end(foo))
> ts_info(bar)

The bar series is a ts object with 1 variable and 21 observations

Frequency: 12 
Start time: 4 4 
End time: 5 12
```

The '1304.6' comes from the third month of the third year of the USVSales ts object

```
> ts_info(USVSales)
 The USVSales series is a ts object with 1 variable and 528 observations
 Frequency: 12 
 Start time: 1976 1 
 End time: 2019 12
 
> baz <- window(USVSales,start=start(USVSales)+3,end=start(USVSales)+6)
> ts_info(baz)

 The baz series is a ts object with 1 variable and 40 observations
 Frequency: 12 
 Start time: 1979 4 
 End time: 1982 7 
> 

head(baz,1)
[1] 1304.6
```